# What "Everyone Must Sign" in Git SCM book about Sign mean?

Tags: git, gnupg

> Everyone Must Sign
>
> Signing tags and commits is great, but if you decide to use this in your normal workflow, you’ll have to make sure that everyone on
> your team understands how to do so. If you don’t, you’ll end up
> spending a lot of time helping people figure out how to rewrite their
> commits with signed versions. Make sure you understand GPG and the
> benefits of signing things before adopting this as part of your
> standard workflow

I found this at https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work

So, I work on a team. If I'm the sole developer that sign my work, is that will ruin my teammate work? eg. They can't pull my work, merge my work, etc?

This sentence really confuse me,

> if you decide to use this in your normal workflow, you’ll have to make sure that everyone on your team understands how to do so.

It seems by signing my commit, I'll force everyone on my team to sign theirs too. Or, have my public key.

Answer (score 2):

The operative wording is

> if you decide to use this in your normal workflow

and

> Make sure you understand GPG and the benefits of signing things before adopting this as part of your standard workflow

Signing is used to prove that the commit has been made by a particular person, similar to how SSL/TLS (among other things) prove that a connection is made to a particular website.

None of this is required for Git to work. In fact, I daresay most Git users never touch this. It's simply a tool that can be used to transmit work over insecure channels for a distributed team.

Comment: To put it simply, its safe for me to sign my work even if none of my coworker sign theirs commit, correct?

Comment: Yes. If you sign your commits or tags, you don't enforce anything unto any others that commit to the same repository.

Comment: The paragraph about "everyone must sign" is simply that if you decide that you need to sign your commits there is nothing in git that enforces this on a per-repo basis, perhaps github or similar can be configured to disallow push with unsigned commits. However, the paragraph simply tells you that you need to ensure everybody on your team learns how to do this, that's all. If you don't, all that happens is that some commits and tags are made unsigned.